# How can a PowerShell job wait on a Job from the parent session?

Tags: powershell, powershell-jobs

In order to do some work when another job completes without blocking the current session, I want to create a job that waits on another, however when create the second job, it cannot detect the first job.

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param([int]$JobId)  Wait-Job -Id $JobId; [Console]::Beep() } -ArgumentList $Job.Id
```

Results in

> The command cannot find a job with the job ID 17. Verify the value of the Id parameter and then try the command again.

It seems when you start a job, it gets its own session with its own job ids.  A job can start sub-jobs and can wait on those jobs.  Is there a way for a job to wait on a job in the *parent* session (a sibling job)?

I can't find anything about this in the [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-6) or [about_Job_Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_job_details?view=powershell-6) documentation.